# jquery datatable sort plugins not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using jquery datatable sort plug-in to sort the currency. However none of the plugin is working for me.

My data in the column is of type:

```
$5,871
$385.58
$430
$1,308.60
```

When there is no **','** and no **"$"** sign in the column then sorting is fine. other wise sorting is not as expected.

Example: sort Output I get(when sorting desc)

```
$890.54
$5.49
$5,871
$2,548.50
```

where as output should have been:

```
$5,871
$2,548.50
$890.54
$5.49
```

I have tried : numeric-comma, currency, title-numeric sort to sort these values.

If I remove the $ and , from these values then they are correctly sorted.

Tried:

1. http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/title-numeric
2. http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/formatted-numbers
3. http://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/numeric-comma

Sorted Output is same always same as above:

There is one more tweak to this problem:

For the columns we do not have any currency it is represented as **"---"**:

Example

```
$5,871
$2,548.50
$890.54
---
---
$5.49
```

Comment: what do you mean by "For the columns we do not have any currency it is represented as "---" " ?

Are there entire columns with "---" ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code. It should work with '$' sign as well. You don't need to remove $ sign.

```
 jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
            "currency-pre": function (a) {
                a = (a === "-") ? 0 : a.replace(/[^\d\-\.]/g, "");
                return parseFloat(a);
            },
            "currency-asc": function (a, b) {

                return a - b;
            },
            "currency-desc": function (a, b) {

                return b - a;
            }
    });

// Initialize datatable

$('#datatableID').dataTable({
            'aoColumns': [
                            { 'sType': 'currency' }],
```

Answer (score 1):

why not build your own extension, its really simple

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
            "currency-pre": function(a) {
            //EDIT: To Accommodate for the "---" columns, use this
                return a.indexOf('--') > -1 ? -1 : a.replace(/\$|,/g, '').trim();
            },
            "currency-asc": function(a, b) {
                return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
            },
            "currency-desc": function(a, b) {
                return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
            });
```

then make sure to set 'sType' to 'currency'

Comment: This also does not work. I tried to edit the regex to /[\$\-,]/ but no luck.